# Issue with the delimter "\t" when manipulating a CSV file with Talend

Tags: excel, csv, talend

I'm doing some filters using Talend in my csv file, the delimter is tab "\t". But  in the output all fields in the delimited file are displayed as a single column !

Here is my job and the setting of my output file

[image]

This is a screenshot from my csv file in the input

[image]

and this is the setiing of my tFileInputDelimited, i'm using the same metadata to read the file in the input and in the output

[image]
Thank u for your help !

Comment: Can you provide some sample data from your CSV file?

Comment: @Viki888 I added a screenshot of my input file

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that you have attached the screenshot of `tfileoutputdelimited` properties, can you kindly attach the screenshot for `tfileinputdelimited` properties?

Comment: Can you post your sample data as text instead of image?

Comment: year month day DateTime AreaTypeCode AreaName MapCode ProductionType_Name ActualConsumption ActualGenerationOutput SubmissionTS
2016 10 28 2016-10-28 11:00:00.000 BZN CEPS BZ CZ Solar  0.000000 617.740000 2016-10-28 15:18:57.000
 .....

Comment: @amani92 which file editor you are using to open the output file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your settings are correct and the file should be delimited by `\t`.

But I think that the software used to open the output file is confusing you, such the case of Ms Excel which need some data conversion to indicate the [correct separator](https://superuser.com/a/606274). See [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/01/convert-csv-excel/) how to correctly import a csv file in Excel and choose the right separator.

Or you can use notepad++ and toggle the show all caracters option to see the `\t` as an orange arrow between fields.

Comment: when i open my output file with notepad, it is like expected (fields separated with tab "\t" ) But, when opening with Excel, i'm getting all fields in one single column

Comment: @amani92, this is exactly what i meant, your file is OK ! i will add to my answer how you deal with excel.